# Underscore in php function

Tags: php, double-underscore

What does it mean when a PHP function name begins with an underscore?

for example: `__construct()`

I know what the construct means but I've seen other places where the function begins with an underscore, or a double underscore and I'm just not sure of the significance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means that PHP calls it implicitly.

It's called a 'Magic Method'

Also, it's two underscores, not one.

Learn more here: [PHP Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: Ah. Magic in PHP. Whatever next?

Comment: I hate hate *hate* that they chose the term "magic" for this convention.  It sounds so childish/idiotic.  Why not just call them "hooks"?

Comment: @Amarghosh Who is everybody? Personally I like it and I know tons of people who like it.

Comment: @Peter Bailey: see http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic.html for a bit of explanation

Comment: @Amarghosh Do you mean everybody hate wordpress, everybody hate magento, everybody hate drupal, codeinginator, cakephp etc. Go out of you room lol i think everybody hate you... (^_~)

Answer (score 5):

In PHP, functions start with two underscores usually have special meanings. From the manual:

> PHP reserves all function names
>   starting with __ as magical. It is
>   recommended that you do not use
>   function names with __ in PHP unless
>   you want some documented magic
>   functionality.

For example __construct() is a special method which is called automatically while initializing an object.

Se also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 4):

There's also a common naming "coding style" which uses one initial underscore to indicate methods or properties are private/protected. I think it's pretty widespread.

Comment: Yes, I have used this in C#

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answers, the double underscore is used for "magic" methods.  The idea is that the user would never intentionally use two underscores for a method name, so there is little risk of collision.  The reason it isn't a single underscore, I believe, is that the single underscore was a popular convention for private methods in the bad(der) old days, before the 'private' keyword came along to enforce OO privateness.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, if you start a method in a controller with an underscore, the router will know not to allow it to be accessed from the url.