# String :: and __ the double colon and double underscore in PHP 

Tags: php, class

What do you call with these string :: and __ in PHP and what other strings are similar to them?

Comment: Duplicate of [What do two colons mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903564/what-do-two-colons-mean-in-php) and [Underscore in PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820973/underscore-in-php-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:: = Scope resolution operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

The __-prefix is a convention surrounded by built-in magic: http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php, never start a function or variable with this if you can avoid it.

The first is a token, the second a convention.

If you really want to know most tokens, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php
If you want to know more about naming conventions, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php

When starting out with PHP it would hurt to read Zend coding conventions, although it's not a must and not the only way by a long shot: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html

Comment: Variable variable: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php Most often used by people who don't know how to use arrays. In about 95% of cases an array would server better then a $$varname.