# What does PHP's underscore function do?

Tags: php

What does this function do?

```
_()
```

Can you link me to the relevant documentation, as searching for "_" is nigh on impossible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you open http://www.php.net/_ you get to the documentation of the _() function and see its for localization stuff (gettext).

Answer (score 14):

`_()` is an alias of [gettext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php).

Answer (score 11):

It's an alias for the [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

Note sure I understand your question but here are some explanations for common scenarios.

- [PHP Magic Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820973/underscore-in-php-function)
- [Old PHP4 method of defining private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods)
- [gettext() alias](http://php.net/_) used for localisation