# Why can't I declare a function name "_"?

Tags: php

Code:

```
function _()
{
    echo 'hello word';
}
```

Output:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _()

I haven't defined this function `_` before, then why I am getting this error?

Comment: @Daniel: The topic you point out is about prefixing methods with an underscore, the OP is asking why they cannot create a function called `_`.

Comment: @Daniel A. White. Nope, not related at all.

Comment: The linked "dupe" is about using `_` to **prefix** method/function names not using **just** `_` alone as the function/method name.

Comment: i thought there was an amazed smiley in the title

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does PHP's underscore function do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413920/what-does-phps-underscore-function-do)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`_()` is an alias for [`gettext`](http://www.php.net/_).

Comment: Guys, seriously? 24 upvotes for a one-sentence answer? Could you please have a look at the answers I actually spend some time on? ;o)

Comment: Maybe you could explain exactly why on earth they made that an alias? Thats almost as bad as Javascripts $ variable.

Comment: @The Because I didn't have any part in the decision I can't explain *exactly* why they did it. It makes perfect sense though, since `_('Foo')` is a lot easier to work with than `gettext('Foo')` if you have a lot of l10nable strings in your app (which is quite a normal scenario). The same reason why JS libraries choose short variable names for often-used functions.

Answer (score 13):

`_` is an alias for [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), a built-in function. Just as you cannot declare a function `gettext`, you can't create a function `_` since one is already there.

Comment: Its the standard name for function that *translates*. You can have such method in a class, for example. :P